# How can I modify my dropdownlist code below to multiple selection version?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I just started to work with Mvc Project and I am a bit far away to use cshtml controller.  As more details, I couldnt modify this dropdownlist to multiple selection like a listbox or etc.

```
VIEW:
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserId, new SelectList(ViewData["User"] as SelectList, "id", "name"), "--Select--", new { @multiple = "multiple", @data_rule_required = "true", @data_msg_required = "Please pick users...", @class = "input-xlarge" })

CONTROLLER:
var userobject = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < perkull.Count; i++)
            {
                userobject.Add(perkull[i].Key, perkull[i].Value);
            }
            ViewData["User"] = new SelectList(userobject, "Key", "Value");

            ViewBag.User = 0;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            {
                int recordid = int.Parse(id);
                var model = db.UserRights.Where(x => x.Id == recordid).SingleOrDefault();
                ViewBag.User = model.UserId;

                return View(model);
            }
            return View();
```

Edited: 
I already had tried to modify this code block for listboxfor, but it didn't work out. Here is what I did :

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.UserId, new MultiSelectList(ViewData["User"] as MultiSelectList, "id", "name"),  new { @multiple = "multiple", @data_rule_required = "true", @data_msg_required = "Please pick users...", @class = "input-xlarge" })
```

Comment: I already had tried to modify this code block for listboxfor, but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.UserIds, new SelectList(ViewData["User"] as SelectList, "id", "name"),  new { @multiple = "multiple", @data_rule_required = "true", @data_msg_required = "Please pick users...", @class = "input-xlarge" })
```

keep in mind I used `UserIds` that is `List<UserId>`

Comment: Right. I totally forgot to use as a list. Thank you for answer.